# Can't upload image to S3 from iOS

Tags: ios, swift, file-upload, amazon-s3

I'm trying to set up an S3 to store profile images for my iOS client. I had it working but I my partner on the other side of the country couldn't upload so were messing around, and now I can't upload either. I can still download the images that are there but that's all.

Here is the code I'm using to upload them:

```
    let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType:.USWest2, identityPoolId: myIdentityPoolId)
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:.USWest2, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)
    AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

    let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
    uploadRequest.body = generateImageUrl(remoteName, image: image)
    uploadRequest.key = remoteName
    uploadRequest.bucket = S3BucketName
    uploadRequest.contentType = "image/jpeg"


    let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.defaultS3TransferManager()

    // Perform file upload
    transferManager.upload(uploadRequest).continueWith(executor: AWSExecutor.mainThreadExecutor(), block: { (task:AWSTask) -> AnyObject? in


        if let error = task.error {
            if error.domain == AWSS3TransferManagerErrorDomain, let code = AWSS3TransferManagerErrorType(rawValue: error.code) {
                switch code {
                case .Cancelled, .Paused:
                    break
                default:
                    print("Error uploading: \(uploadRequest.key)")
                }
            } else {
                print("Error uploading: \(uploadRequest.key)")
            }
            return nil
        }

        let uploadOutput = task.result
        print("Upload complete for: \(uploadRequest.key)")
        return nil
```

I'm getting these errors:

```
2017-03-08 ... [] nw_endpoint_flow_prepare_output_frames [10.1 52.218.128.128:443 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] Failed to use 1 frames, marking as failed
2017-03-08 ... [] nw_endpoint_handler_add_write_request [10.1 52.218.128.128:443 failed socket-flow (satisfied)] cannot accept write requests
2017-03-08 ... [] __tcp_connection_write_eof_block_invoke Write close callback received error: [22] Invalid argument
2017-03-08 ... AWSiOSSDK v2.5.1 [Error] AWSURLSessionManager.m line:212 | -[AWSURLSessionManager URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:] | Session task failed with error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x17005c560 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=<myUrl>, NSErrorFailingURLKey=<myUrl>, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated. This is the first time I have used S3 and I'm still pretty lost. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: So it turns out that my friend had a different version of the pods and when I pulled his version I got the out of date ones too. We struggled for about a week before we found the solution, `pod update`.

TL/DR: `pod update`